# How to connect to Bluemix dashDB outside the Bluemix environment

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have several tables in dashDB and I want to access them from another server in order to filter out the data and insert it to a database on my own server.

In dashDB, there is a `Service Credentials` section and I clicked "Add Credentials" and it outputted a json file with service credentials info.

I tried to run a simple PHP to test the connection :

```
<?php
$servername = "dashdb-entry-....";
$username = "dash....";
$password = "....";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

and it fails. The error is as follow:

```
Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to   respond.
```

I checked service status of IBM and it seems that everything is running. Is it possible to access the dashDB outside the Blumix environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to connect to dashDB from outside Bluemix. [Here](https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview) you can find some samples on how to connect to dashDB using several programming languages. Please take a look at the [PHP Sample](https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/ibmdatabase%252FdashDB/list/master/samples/dashDBPHP): One first difference I can see is that you are using mysqli while you should use db2_connect as in the sample.

Comment: The  pastebin.com/N4LGRgA6 example can only work as is inside Bluemix since it consumes the VCAP_SERVICES environment. But you should provide in your code a conn_string similar to the one that the example compiles. Actually you should be able to take it mostly from the dashed service credentials that you already have identified.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to the dashdb on bluemix using PHP. I also found the following link that explains this in detail.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php

You can also use ODBC or JDBC method with proper drivers installed on the client and providing the connection credentials found under the 
connect --> connection information
from the left hand side after you log in.

Murali